# Cron expression to schedule a job, monday to friday

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am using "cron(0 21 * * ? *)" as a cron expression to run my glue job every day. However, I want to change it, and make my job run just monday to friday. How could I do it? May you guys help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `day-of-week` component and unset the `day-of-month`:

```
cron(0 21 ? * MON-FRI *)
```

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-data-warehouse-schedule.html

See also https://eu-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/glue/home?region=eu-west-1#/v2/etl-configuration/triggers/add to build and inspect cron based triggers.